# Why does FaceTime preview video have a wider angle than in call?

Tags: camera, facetime

When trying to setup a good angle for a FaceTime call, e.g., kids calling their grandparents while at the dining table, I can see both kids in the preview screen.

However, when the call starts, the angle is narrower, and both kids can’t be seen easily, making me move the iPad / iPhone backwards to get a better view.

Why is there a difference in between the 2 field of view angles?  Shouldn’t FaceTime preview match what will *exactly* happen during the call?

Comment: Are both parties holding their devices in the same orientation? If one is landscape & the other portrait, it can reframe. Also, knowing the precise devices may help, as they're not all the same display ratio.

Comment: Yes, both are in landscape.